# Invoke-DscResource against a resource without a module

Tags: powershell, dsc

On the current version of WMF5, I try and invoke a DSC resource using Invoke-DSCResource like so:

```
$destinationPath="$env:SystemDrive\DirectAccess.txt"
$fileContents="This file is create by Invoke-DscResource"
$result = Invoke-DscResource -Name File -Method Test -Property @{
DestinationPath=$destinationPath
Contents=$fileContents } -Verbose
$result | fl *
```

However, I'm asked for a module name for the "File" resource.

Doing Get-DscResource File lists the dsc resource, but the "module" property is empty. How can I figure out which module to pass Invoke-DscResource? Where (in what module) does the "File" resource really live?

Answer (score 1):

PSDesiredStateConfiguration was the correct module (can be seen in compiled mof when using the file resource). Apparently "File" is a weird DSC resource.

Answer (score -1):

The File resource in DSC is implemented as a WMI provider (*the only resource that way)* while the rest of the resources are implemented as PowerShell resources. Invoke-DscResource only works with PowerShell resources hence you will not be able to invoke it on File.

Comment: I'm afraid this is incorrect. `Invoke-DscResource` works with binary/WMI resources and PowerShell resources. It does not work with composite resources. As @Trondh found, File is a strange resource in that you must _infer_ the (required) module name is `PSDesiredStateConfiguration` whereas other resources will show it, through `Get-DscResource`.